# How to use RegExReplace in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: regex, replace, google-sheets

I'm trying to remove beggining numbers from a column in a Google Docs spreadsheet using regex. I can't get RegExReplace function to work. This is the error I get when I run/debug the code:

```
Missing ) after argument list. (line 14)
```

This is a part of my code (line 14 is the RegExReplace function line, bolded):

```
regexFormat = "^[0-9]+$";
replVal = value.RegExReplace(value; regexFormat; "");  //error here

rplc.setValue(replVal);
```

This is the official syntax: `RegExReplace( text ; regular_expression ; replacement )`

Anyone knows how to use this function? Thanks!

Comment: Don't know Google Spreadsheets, but are you sure the argument separator is a semicolon (`;`) instead of a comma (`,`)? Semicolon is typically a statement terminator (like you've used it at the end of the `regexFormat =` statement).

Comment: Yes, I'm quite sure, see the official syntax: RegExReplace( text ; regular_expression ; replacement )

Comment: OK. Just checking; like I said, I'm not familar with Google Spreadsheets. Thought it might be worth checking. (That's why I posted a comment and not an answer.) :)

Comment: @conualfy do you have a sample of the original text your trying to edit and the expected outcome?  I use Regexreplace and regexextract in gs every day

Comment: That's not a spreadsheet formula, it's Google Apps Script, which is a variant of JavaScript. JavaScript statements are (optionally) terminated by a semicolon. So, simply put, you've terminated a statement after `value;`, with no closing bracket. Just a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found another solution for replacing with regexp in Google Docs Script:

```
var replace = '';//because we want to remove matching text
var regexp2 = new RegExp("[0-9]*[\.]*");//an example of regexp to do the job
var valcurat = value.replace(regexp2, replace);//working
```

As I did not find any solution for RegExReplace, I changed the method with replace(regexp, new_text). This one works.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know why the docs list a semicolon, but if you are doing it as a spreadsheet function, you still need to use commas.  Try the following:

`=REGEXREPLACE("What-A Crazy str3ng", "\W", "")`

Which as expected, yields

`WhatACrazystr3ng`

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess but if the function is Javaish, maybe there are 2 forms.
Form 1:
`myvar = RegExReplace(value; regexFormat; "");`
Form2:
`myvar = value.RegExReplace(regexFormat; "");`

Comment: Just tried the one with only 2 parameters and it fails to run.
`TypeError: Cannot find function RegExReplace in object 6. Caracal (şi parcul Constantin Poroineanu). (line 14)`

It looks like some other parameter is expected.